# How to run a Docker agent without steps on Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I have a `Jenkinsfile` defining a lot of stages on my build pipeline. The thing is that one of those stages don't need any step because the container runs what it needs to run at startup with my code inside it and that's it.

The problem is that I can't specify a `stage` with a Docker `agent` without the `steps` section. So does anyone know how can I manage this?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
stage('Sonarqube Analysis') {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'My Docker Image'
            args 'my docker image args'
        }
    }
    steps {
        sh 'echo "useless step"'
    }
}
```

The real thing is that I need to remove this is step because it would never be executed, since my container dies after it's internal command runs.

Comment: `because the container runs what it needs to run at startup with my code inside it and that's it.` it probably doesn't, when jenkins runs it. Just call the entrypoint from jenkins.

Comment: @tkausl this is the problem. When I put this configuration Jenkins calls the container's `entrypoint` that runs the command and that's what I want it to do. So an alternative to this would be create my own image extending the cloud image and then put my own command/entrypoint but I'm trying to figure out another way.